# Why can we write $\displaystyle\lim f(x)=f\left({\displaystyle\lim x}\right)$?

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Can someone explain to me why we can do something like $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} e^x=e^{(\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x)}$ or $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\log(x)=\log {(\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x)}$? I have learned this in school to use, but no one proved it. It can only be used on continous functions. If this question was previously asked sorry, but I couldnt find my answer or I wasn't asking the right question.

Comment: Actually this is a characterization of continuous functions. What is your definition of continuous function?

Comment: Do you want to know why this is possible in a general manner, or a rigorous proof why specific functions like $e$ and $\log$ satisfy it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the theorem that for a continuous function $f$ $$\lim f(g(x))=f(\lim g(x))$$

Comment: Like I said, I got used to this but I have no idea why it is like that.
Do you have an article about it, it would help a lot. I don't like the feeling to use something I don't understand.